# Custom sequence or windows function in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, grouping, window-functions

I have a huge table which looks like this

```
Group | Code | Value
------|------|------
G1    |0     |V1
G1    |2     |V2
G1    |2     |V3     
G1    |1     |V4
G1    |2     |V5
G1    |2     |V6

G2    |0     |V7
G2    |1     |V8
G2    |1     |V9     
G2    |2     |V10
G2    |2     |V11
G2    |2     |V12
G2    |2     |V13
```

I need to generate a table like this

```
Group | Code | Value
------|------|------
G1    |0     |V1
G1    |2     |V2+V3
G1    |1     |V4
G1    |2     |V5+V6

G2    |0     |V7
G2    |1     |V8
G2    |1     |V9     
G2    |2     |V10+V11
G2    |2     |V12+V13
```

The value `code = 2` always appears as a pair and I need to sum up two consecutive values of `code = 2`. Any ideas of how to do it using just SQL statements instead of stored procedures? Any special features that could help me do this. I'm trying Postgres 9.6 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want the rows to be sorted by the numeric part of the `Value` column. If we call `t` the table, here's a query that does what you want using window functions:

```
SELECT "group", code, string_agg(value, '+')
FROM
   (SELECT *, (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "group", code ORDER BY n) - 1) / CASE code WHEN 2 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS code_group
    FROM (SELECT *,substr(value,2)::integer AS n FROM t) t1
   ) t2
GROUP BY "group", code, code_group
ORDER BY min(n);
```

The idea is to first to extract (in a subquery) the numeric part of `value` so that we can use it later on as a sort key. Then we use the following complex exression:

```
(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "group", code ORDER BY n) - 1) / CASE code WHEN 2 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
```

This basically assigns to each group of rows (grouped by `group`, `code`) an increasing number starting with 0. So the first row is 0, the next one is 1 and so on. But there is an exception to that. If `code` is 2, then we use the following numbering scheme: 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, .... This is accomplished by dividing the row number by 2. I call this number, the `code_group`. In the last step, we group by `group`, `code` (like before) but also `code_group` so that pairs of consecutive row with `code=2` collapse into one.

Comment: Perfect!! My case is little simpler as the Value column in of type `real` and I don't have to sort them by value (my bad, should have phrased the question better), but your logic is sweet and nice. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from (
    select 
        grp, code, 
        case when code = 2 then
            case when rn & 1 = 1 then null
            else concat(lag(value) over w, '+', value)
            end
        else value
        end as value
    from (
        select *, row_number() over w rn
        from a_table
        window w as (partition by code order by grp, code)
        ) s
    window w as (order by grp, code, rn)
    ) s
where value notnull
order by grp, code
```

Steps:

- add row numbers over partition by group and code

  - if code = 2 and its row number is odd then select null as value
  - if code = 2 and its row number is even then concat its and previous values as value
  - if code <> 2 then just select value
- skip rows with null values.